# Angular JS using $resource throwing error : Error: [$injector:unpr] Unknown provider: $resourceProvider <- $resource <- MyController

Tags: angularjs, angular-resource

I am getting the error "Unknown Provider".
I have searched throught the forums and implemented all suggestions(marked as answer, as well).
But error isnt resolved. Please guide. Below is the code:

In html, am referring  1. angular.min.js 2.angular-resource.js  3.App.js 4.MyJS in the same order.

In my app.js:

```
angular.module('myApp', [ 'ngSanitize', 'ngCookies','ngResource'  ]);

angular.module('myApp')    
.controller('MainCtrl', ['$rootScope','$resource', function($rootScope) {
     //my code goes here//
       }]);
```

In another JS file:

```
angular.module('myApp')
.controller('myController', 
['$scope', '$rootScope', '$http', '$window', '$cookies', '$resource', function ($scope, $rootScope, $http, $window, $cookies, $resource) 
{ ---- My Code -----    }
```

I have seen the forums and suggestions and ensured app.js is called first. angular-resource.js is referred after referring angular.min.js.

Please suggest where am going wrong.

Thank You

Comment: You putting script angular-resource.js in project? http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.2.16/angular-resource.min.js

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Should be

```
['$rootScope','$resource', function($rootScope, $resource) {
```

instead of

```
['$rootScope','$resource', function($rootScope) {
```

Number of controllers function parameters should be same as number of string literals.

Comment: Thank You for the response. I am using $resource in this controller:  myController and I do have $resource injected there. Also, added $resource to MainCtrl. Still no luck !

Comment: Thank You , this really helped!